# jquery-ui tabs works but I cannot get any event binding to work, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: jquery, select, jquery-ui-tabs

It does not respond to any action I have tried, onclick onchange and select. I have googled and read many answers but I am unable to see what I am doing wrong.

```
  <input name="form_date" id="form_date" type="date" value = <?php echo date("Y-m-d");?>>

  <script>
     $(function() {
        $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
     });
  </script>

  <script>
     $("#tabs").tabs({
         select: function(event, ui) {
             alert("PRESSED TAB!");
         }
     });      
  </script>
```

I am rapidly becoming bald!

Comment: You need a doctor.. Not a StackOverflow-er :P   Have you loaded the jquery and the tabs library properly ? Also, any console errors in the browser ?

Comment: The tabs work well, I have checked that I loaded jquery and jquery-ui OK. The only error in the console is "@charset "UTF-8";"

Answer (score 0):

Use the Tab Activation event handler I don't think select will work. See example here

http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#event-activate

```
$( ".selector" ).tabs({
  activate: function( event, ui ) {}
});
```

Comment: thank you I checked the link and also tried "$( ".selector" ).on( "tabsactivate", function( event, ui ) {alert("PRESSED TAB!");} );". It did not work either. Looks like I have to dump jquery-ui tabs.